# Why doesn't ArrayList print correctly?

Tags: c#, arraylist, tostring

```
ArrayList c = new ArrayList();
c.Add(new Continent("Africa", af));
c.Add(new Continent("America", am));
c.Add(new Continent("Asia", a));
c.Add(new Continent("Oceania", oc));
c.Add(new Continent("Europe", eu));

c.Sort();

for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}", c[i]);
}


output:

TP.Continent
TP.Continent
TP.Continent
TP.Continent
TP.Continent
```

The constructor is fine because it sorts without telling me there's an error

the first element is a string, the other is a integer. It should be fine, but it doesn't print correctly for some reason.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` and `for` loops like it's 2002?

Comment: Are you seriously asking the reason its converting your `Type` to a `String`?  Please do more research before asking a quesiton.

Answer (score 7):

You are printing Continent objects, not their individual parts.  You can either change your loop to be:

```
for (int i=0; i<c.Count; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}", c[i].name); // Or whatever attributes it has
}
```

Or you can add a "ToString" function inside "Continent" object to correctly print it out.

This would look like (inside the Continent object):

```
public override string ToString()
{
return "Continent: " + attribute; // Again, change "attribute" to whatever the Continent's object has
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're telling it to print the *object* at `c[i]`, which calls `c[i].ToString()`, which rturns the name of the type.

The language does not have insight into what members of this object you would actually like to print.  So, if you want to print (for example) the name of the continent you will need to pass that to `Console.WriteLine`.  That, or you can override `ToString` for your type to return a more meaningful string.

On a side note, there are almost no good reasons to use an `ArrayList` anymore.  Prefer a strongly typed generic collection instead, i.e.,

```
var list = new List<Continent>();
list.Add(new Continent("", whatever)); // ok
list.Add(1); // fails! The ArrayList would allow it however
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the behavior you're looking for by overriding `ToString()` in your `Continent` class.

`Console.WriteLine` converts objects to strings by calling the `ToString` method on each object.  `Object.ToString()` returns the name of the object's type.  You haven't overridden the method in your type, so ToString is returning the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the ArrayList problem, it's the problem with the Continent class. Here's the deal: whenever you try to print an object, CLR invokes that object ToString() method to get it's user-friendly visual representation.

To show your continents better, you have to go to Continent class and add following lines:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each element is of type Continent, you need to cast before printing them out:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}",((Continent)c[i]).YourProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your arraylist contains objects of type Continent. By doing Console.WriteLine("{0}", c[i]);

you are printing an entire Continent object. I don't know the fields of your Continent object. But If you want to print out the string value, you should print out that field instead. For example if your class looks like this

`Class Continent
    {
    private String continentName;
    public getContinent()
    {
    return continentName;
    }
    }`

Then you should do
Console.WriteLine("{0}", c[i].getContinent());